# perl command to create matrix.txt

Tags: windows, perl, cmd

I have a txt file from a blast output containing each query with its hit and its % identity and score and I need to convert to matrix file to create a heatmap
I used this long command:

```
perl -we "while (<>) {chomp; @col = split /\t/; push @{$score{$col[0]}{$col[1]}}, $col[2], $col[3]}  @array = keys %score; print join "\t", "", @array, ""."\n"; foreach $key (keys %score) {print "$key\t";  foreach $hit (@array) {if ($score{$key}{$hit}) {print "$score{$key}{$hit}[0]\t" } else {print "\t"} } print "\n" }"
```

but I get a comment that: unquoted string `"t"` may clash with future reserved word at `-e` line 1

and the file generated was 0 KB in size

highly appreciate your help

Comment: Please properly format your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: `"while (<>) {chomp; @col = split /\t/; push @{$score{$col[0]}{$col[1]}}, $col[2], $col[3]}  @array = keys %score; print join "` - If your string starts with `"`, it ends at the next `"`. Also, what shell are you using?

Comment: I think it ends with "    and if you please what do you mean by shell?

Comment: I think it ends with double quotes and if you please what do you mean by shell?

Comment: If you know the code ends at `... print join "`, what do you think `\t", "", @array, ""."\n` is?

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/EQ2F9XFe) avoids the trailing blank field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `"..."` with `qq/.../` everywhere, so for instance

```
"$score{$key}{$hit}[0]\t"
```

becomes

```
qq/$score{$key}{$hit}[0]\t/
```

But seriously, this is a ludicrously long piece of code to put into a one-liner. Put it into a file, let's say `matrix.pl` and run `perl matrix.pl`. That way it will be *much* easier for you to read and edit, and much better for anyone else to help you

Here's the properly laid-out version of your code

#### matrix.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %score;

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    my @col = split /\t/;
    push @{ $score{$col[0]}{$col[1]} }, $col[2], $col[3];
}

my @keys = keys %score;

print join "\t", "", @keys, "" . "\n";

for my $key ( @keys ) {

    print "$key\t";

    for my $hit ( @keys ) {

        if ( $score{$key}{$hit} ) {
            print "$score{$key}{$hit}[0]\t";
        }
        else {
            print "\t";
        }
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your help, but i m not expert in perl, would you please tell me how can i give a command using this matrix.pl file

Comment: I told you: `perl matrix.pl` is equivalent to the line you have in your question. You will need to supply some data for it to work, but that doesn't change.

Comment: sorry i got it, yiu already wrote it in your comment. Many thanks again, you really helped me in a problem I was stuck in for almost a week